# Issue with content slider width

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am using the following slider :

[Content Slider](http://www.copterlabs.com/demo/contentslider/)

I am facing an issue though. When i give the width 100% in the function, then the slides disappear and shows blank white area. Following is the function that is used to call the slider :

```
$(function() { 
   $('#two').ContentSlider({ 
            width : '600px', 
            height : '266px', 
            speed : 400, 
            easing : 'easeOutQuad', 
            textResize : true 
   }); 
});
```

Instead of 600px I am giving it a 100% width, but when i do so, it doesn't show any slides. Any ideas? [Link to the html](http://singhharmeet.com/digitize/)

Comment: Maybe the slider does not support responsive sizes? I couldn't find any documentation on the slider they're using. Do you have to use this one?

Comment: I want to use a slider which has 2 parts/sections. One on the left would be the image and right div containing text. As this site is 100% width so i cant use the regular nivo sliderkit etc plugins as they take up a whole lot of space when viewed on large screens. Any alternate you could suggest please then i'll be thankful.

Comment: I recomend this plugin: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ . Is so much better. And it handle it your issue perfectly

Comment: Looks good. Will apply it and let you know in a couple.

Comment: All is well thanks. The plugin is very easy and its options well explained. Thanks again.